# Why is TargetInvokationException introduced to C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I've been playing around with `Invoke` method and realized when an exception is thrown in the target method, a `TargetInvokationException` raises actually. I don't understand why C# creators used this approach. It doesn't make sense to me.

I mean, why not throw the original Exception instead of throwing a secondary exception having the original one as its InnerException?

Comment: `Invoke` also throws more common exception types like `InvalidOperationException` and `ArgumentException` - if you're catching one of these, there's the chance for ambiguity whether or not it was raised by the reflection class itself, or by the target, which you may handle differently. `TargetInvocationException` is unambiguous as to where the exception was generated.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be pedantic, this is a .Net framework exception - not a C# exception.

Using reflection means you can have a very loose coupling between your caller and callee (method that initiates the call, and the ultimate target methods that are called). 
The source and target can be in totally different assemblies that are not linked at compile time and know nothing of each other. Due to the dynamic nature of this process it is correct to take an [event aggregation approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee321571.aspx), wrapping it and then throwing the new exception. The same approach is also used in other places like the TPL, where an error thrown in a task is wrapped in a [System.Aggregate exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before being rethrown.

Answer (score 1):

`Invoke` (or `DynamicInvoke`) can throw own exceptions, before of after executing a "real" method.

`TargetInvocationException` allows to determine what would have been the cause of the error: code in the delegate class or in method.